# Cas (for authentication ) + OpenLDAP ( for username, password + roles and permissions ) + Apache Shiro ( for authorization )

Tags: cas, openldap, shiro

As stated, I am developing a springboot application with following tech stack:
1. CAS for SSO
2. LDAP for usrname, password storage

Till here all works fine. Now I need to add apache shiro for authorization. I am not sure about what should be the realm definition as I don't want authentication to be done by Shiro. I am not able to find any decent example with this combination.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. Shiro gives too many things.. Authentication + authorization + encryption etc.

In my case, ACL can be achieved using CustomVoter in spring security.

Hence, decided not to use Shiro.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Buji project for Shiro with CAS support: http://www.pac4j.org/